# as3: how to emulate MouseEvents?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, adobe

How can i "emulate" a `MouseEvent`, that **has not been initiated by a button** with a `eventListener` 
(e.g. *just by a simple function call*) and how can i pass variables into it to switch the `event.types`?

```
    public function myMouseEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case "mouseDown" :
                     trace(event.type)
                     break;

                case "mouseUp" :
                     trace(event.type)
                     break;
            }
    }

    myMouseEvent(null) // ? nothing happens...
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? do you need to emulate the mouse behavior?

Comment: yes, exactly ! :) (mouseDown, mouseUp + set the event.target )

Comment: Have you alredy created your own event and your own listener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1/ **Basic**

In your case you can call directly

```
myMouseEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
```

2/ **Event**

But you could do it in a more event-oriented manner.

```
eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
```

where `eventDispatcher` is the Sprite ([or something else](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html)) you added your listener to.

3/ **Proper Event**

Since your can't access to all properties of the [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) when you dispatch it like that, there is a cleaner way to do it:

```
public function myMouseEvent(event:Event):void
{
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case "mouseDown" :
                 trace(event.type)
                 break;

            case "mouseUp" :
                 trace(event.type)
                 break;
        }
}
eventDispatcher.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myMouseEvent);
eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
```

All three may work!

Comment: Excellent answer. With some links to the doc, it would have been flawless.

Comment: I think something else that needs to be asked is 'Why'?  Why do you need to emulate a mouse event?  Seems like you're trying to hack something together that should need to in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The `myMouseEvent( null )` call should actually give you an `Exception` as you're trying to access a parameter (`type`) on a null object.

To call this properly, you just need to create a MouseEvent object to pass to the function:

```
// add in any other params, like localX, stageX, etc
var m:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN );
this.myMouseEvent( m );
```

Alternatively, you can use `dispatchEvent()` if you want to go through the event system. Something like

```
this.stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.myMouseEvent );
this.dispatch( m ); // stage will catch this event
```